# Vue watch for pending http requests

Tags: vue.js, http, https, axios

When mounting a component, it starts 4 http requests (using Axios) to get the appropriate data it needs. Is there a way to watch for any pending HTTP requests?

So basically:

Any pending HTTP requests?

yes -> Loading=true

no -> Loading=false

Answer (score 1):

You could use Promise.allSettled() ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)):

```
const request1 = axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
request1.then( ... );
const request2 = axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
request2.then( ... );

Promise.allSettled([request1, request2]).then(() => this.loading = false);
```